# scanning specific line from textfile in java

Tags: java, io

i have a textfile like this

WEOQNWENNQNEWQNEQWEOI

FRJIREJFPWJEIJRIQJERJP

**DATE   :13/05/13 06:09:03

ID       :6034

TICKET_ID:7865

TRANS    :TICKETS

AMOUNT   : 200,000.00**
DSANOJNDONAJN
NENFONQ
NFQOFNOEFOLNFOLNS
NFALJNLFNNNEWFJE
FNLJWNFWOLNENWFNWJNWNOJEF
ENFNJENON
**DATE   :13/05/13 06:09:03

ID       :6034

TICKET_ID:7865

TRANS    :TICKETS

AMOUNT   : 200,000.00**
DQEJNBQEFBNEFOFNNFNOWE
JNWEOFNWENFWN
**DATE   :13/05/13 06:09:03

ID       :6034

TICKET_ID:7865

TRANS    :TICKETS

AMOUNT   : 200,000.00**
NQEONFNQNFNNFEWOFNEWOJNOL
**DATE   :13/05/13 06:09:03

ID       :6034

TICKET_ID:7865

TRANS    :TICKETS

AMOUNT   : 200,000.00**

the problem is, how can i get specific bold line(non encrypted line) in java, or can someone tell me how to jump to specific line?

Comment: and exactly how do you tell what's encrypted and what's not apart? while not particularly likely, a crypted line **COULD** start with `DATE` or `AMOUNT`... if `:` is not possible within the cyphertext, then simply scan for line with a `:` in them...

Comment: i just want to get the bold line/ i want to take the information of the date, id, ticket_id,trans,amount which separated by "let's say" encrypted line

Answer (score 2):

You can read every line and when you get a line which starts with the field name you need to you can decode that line and ignore the rest.  Any tool which read to a line number will also have to read all the lines in between unless you have built an index of the file already (this will need ot read every line, but only once)

Are you sure it's encrypted and not simply a binary file?

Comment: yes it's encrypted, but i just need to jump to the blok of line that i want, i just wish that java has a method like readLine(startline,endline)

Comment: @alamcaputra may be you are looking for [Class RandomAccessFile#seek()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long))

Comment: @alamcaputra Given there is any amount of encrypted data in between, how do you know which line numbers you are interested in.  I don't see how you can avoid checking each line yourself.  Note: you might get encrypted data at the start of a line of interest.

Comment: i think seek() is just for giving the starting positions of the string(cmiiw), but how can i set the position of the line from the textfile

Comment: @alamcaputra You can use seek() but you need to know the index of the  byte the line starts at. e.g. if the line starts at byte 123456789 you can do `raf.seek(123456789);`

Comment: @PeterLawrey i just need to compare the line with the string "TRANS :TICKETS" and the the blok of line that i want is from x-3(startline) until x+1(endline)

Comment: @alamcaputra So you can read each line, keeping the last three.  When you see `TRANS :TICKETS` you can process the next line and the last three.

Comment: Thx guys, i have an idea to solved the problems, just use nextline) from scanner,

Comment: @alamcaputra Exactly what I suggested in the first place ;)  Don't forget that the start of the first line might have leading encrypted data you might want to discard.